# Error mysql: unknown variable 'ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY' connecting to Mysql RDS using certificate

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-rds

While trying to learn about aws services, I'm trying to connect to RDS instance from my ec2 instance using certificate.

I'm using this command to connect -

```
mysql -h <aws-account>.rdsinstance.<region>.rds.amazonaws.com --ssl-ca=rds-ca-2019-root.pem --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY
```

**But i get this error -**
*mysql: unknown variable 'ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY'*

I'm able to connect without certificate using this command:
mysql -h .rdsinstance..rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u admin -p

Has anyone seen this before? I searched around but couldn't find anything that would help me.

If you have any suggestions/solutions please let me know

MyMysql version:
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.68-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Answer (score 4):

Looks like mysql --help does not have --ssl-mode option. I removed it and was able to connect. (below is the command i used, just for reference)

```
mysql -h <aws-account>.rdsinstance.<region>.rds.amazonaws.com --ssl-ca=rds-ca-2019-root.pem -u <user> -P 33306 -p
```

in mysql firing >'status' command confirmed SSL is being used for connection.

Comment: It looks like `--ssl-mode` is missing from the final list at the bottom of the help output, but if you scroll up (or grep for it) it is listed higher up in the help content. It is also listed in [the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-options.html#option_general_ssl-mode). The command you were using should have worked. I did find that this option may be missing from the mariadb mysql client.

Comment: As it is, you are connecting over SSL, but you aren't verifying the SSL certificate matches the RDS server hostname, so you aren't entirely eliminating any MitM attack potential.